# Null form field when sending form with ajax, C# MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to save data in database from a form with `$.ajax`. The problem is that when I submit the form the username is saved as `null`. The email and password are saved correctly.

```js
function SaveForm() {
  var name = $("#User").val();
  var pwd = $("#Password").val();
  var email = $("#Email").val();
  if (name == "" || pwd == "" || email == "") {
      $("#message1").hide();
      $("#message2").show();
      return false;
  }
  var data =  $("#Registration").serialize();
  $.ajax({
      type: "post",
      data: data,
      url: "/Registration/SaveData",
      success: function (result) {
          $("#message1").show();
          $("#message2").hide();
          $("#Registration")[0].reset();
      }            
  });
}
```

```html
<div class="modal-body">
  <form id="Registration">
      <div class="form-group">
          <div class="input-group">
              <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
              <input class="form-control" type="text" name="User" id="User" placeholder="UserName" />
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
          <div class="input-group">
              <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></span>
              <input class="form-control" type="email" name="Email" id="Email" placeholder="Email" />
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
          <div class="input-group">
              <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i></span>
              <input class="form-control" type="password" name="Password" id="Password" placeholder="Password" />
          </div>
      </div>
  </form>
  <div class="form-group">
      <button class="btn btn-info form-control" type="submit" onclick="SaveForm()"><i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i>Submit</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
public JsonResult SaveData(SiteUser model) {
    model.IsValid = false;
    db.SiteUsers.Add(model);
    db.SaveChanges();
    BuildEmailTemplate(model.ID);
    return Json("Registration Successfull", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); 
}
```

Comment: How SiteUser model look like?

Comment: probably you are have UserName in model but in form you sending name.

Comment: Check the property name in your model class. The names and case of the name should match in both places. "User" in html should match with "User" in model class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative way to handle the values for your form:

```
function SaveForm() {
  var name = $("#User").val();
  var pwd = $("#Password").val();
  var email = $("#Email").val();

  var json = {
          name:name,
          pwd:pwd,
          email:email
         };

  if (name == "" || pwd == "" || email == "") {
      $("#message1").hide();
      $("#message2").show();
      return false;
  }

  $.ajax({
      type: "post",
      dataType: "json",
      data: {"json": JSON.stringify(json)},,
      url: "@Url.Action("SaveData","Registration")",
      success: function (result) {
          $("#message1").show();
          $("#message2").hide();
          $("#Registration")[0].reset();
      }            
  });
}
```

And your `Controller` will look like:

```
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

[HttpPost]
public JsonResult SaveData(string json) 
{

    var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    dynamic jsondata = serializer.Deserialize(json, typeof(object));

    //Get your variables here from AJAX call
    var name= jsondata["name"];
    var pwd= jsondata["pwd"];
    var email= jsondata["email"];

    //Set your model here:
    SiteUser model=new SiteUser();
    model.name=name;
    model.pwd=pwd;
    model.email=email;

    //Perform db actions
    db.SiteUsers.Add(model);
    db.SaveChanges();
    BuildEmailTemplate(model.ID);
    return Json("Registration Successfull", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add `dataType` & `contentType` like below.

```
$.ajax({
  dataType: 'json',   
  contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8', 
  type: "post",
  data: $("#Registration").serialize(),
  url: "/Registration/SaveData",
  success: function (result) {
      $("#message1").show();
      $("#message2").hide();
      $("#Registration")[0].reset();
  }            
});
```

Comment: I've been tried that already but when I am adding contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
it gives me a such kind of error: 
 SaveData:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)